# Named function calls jScrollPane ScrollTo

Tags: jquery-jscrollpane

I'm trying to use jScrollPane ScrollTo function like in the code below, but instead of clicking on a div I want a named function to trigger jScrollPane ScrollTo. I'm using ExternalInterface.call in order to initiate ScrollTo from my actionscript code. That's why I need a named function here. 
Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance

```
$(function()
        {
            var pane = $('.scroll-pane');
            pane.jScrollPane(
                {
                    showArrows: true,
                    animateScroll: true
                }
            );

                var api = pane.data('jsp');

            $('#scroll-to').bind(
                'click',
                function()
                {
                    api.scrollTo(100, 100);
                    return false;
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Instead of writing this:

$('#scroll-to').bind(
                    'click',
                    function()
                    {
                        api.scrollTo(100, 100);
                        return false;
                    }
                );
```

you could use this:

```
function scrollToDiv(){

var pane = $('.scroll-pane');
var api = pane.data('jsp');
api.scrollTo(100, 100);
return false;
}
```

If you want a variable scrolling:

```
 function scrollToDiv(x,y){

    var pane = $('.scroll-pane');
    var api = pane.data('jsp');

    api.scrollTo(x, y);
    return false;
    }
```

and : scrollToDiv(100,100);